# Maven shade plugin detects os release with wrong output format: "os.detected.release.like."rhel"" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements

Tags: java, xml, linux, maven, rhel

I am trying to use maven to compile the Apache Beam project. It works on OSX. But, when I switch to Linux, it produces the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (bundle-and-repackage) on project beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java: Error creating shaded jar: The name "os.detected.release.like."rhel"" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML names cannot contain the character """. -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-shade-plugin:2.4.1:shade (bundle-and-repackage) on project beam-runners-google-cloud-dataflow-java: Error creating shaded jar: The name "os.detected.release.like."rhel"" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML names cannot contain the character """.
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:120)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:355)
        at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:216)
        at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:160)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:95)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:508)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Error creating shaded jar: The name "os.detected.release.like."rhel"" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML names cannot contain the character """.  
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:539)
        at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:132)
        at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
        ... 19 more
Caused by: org.jdom.IllegalNameException: The name "os.detected.release.like."rhel"" is not legal for JDOM/XML elements: XML names cannot contain the character """.
        at org.jdom.Element.setName(Element.java:207)
        at org.jdom.Element.<init>(Element.java:141)
        at org.jdom.DefaultJDOMFactory.element(DefaultJDOMFactory.java:134)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.updateElement(MavenJDOMWriter.java:1485)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.findAndReplaceSimpleElement(MavenJDOMWriter.java:164)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.findAndReplaceProperties(MavenJDOMWriter.java:125)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.updateProfile(MavenJDOMWriter.java:1929)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.iterateProfile(MavenJDOMWriter.java:878)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.updateModel(MavenJDOMWriter.java:1653)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.MavenJDOMWriter.write(MavenJDOMWriter.java:2190)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.pom.PomWriter.write(PomWriter.java:75)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.rewriteDependencyReducedPomIfWeHaveReduction(ShadeMojo.java:1023)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.createDependencyReducedPom(ShadeMojo.java:957)
        at org.apache.maven.plugins.shade.mojo.ShadeMojo.execute(ShadeMojo.java:531)
        ... 21 more
```

It seems that the maven shade plugin is trying to detect the os release id. But, the return value is wrapped with a quote mark ("rhel"), which is illegal in JDOM/XML. Below is the content in /etc/os-releases:

```
NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server"
VERSION="7.2 (Maipo)"
ID="rhel"
ID_LIKE="fedora"
VERSION_ID="7.2"
PRETTY_NAME="Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server 7.2 (Maipo)"
ANSI_COLOR="0;31"
CPE_NAME="cpe:/o:redhat:enterprise_linux:7.2:GA:server"
HOME_URL="https://www.redhat.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugzilla.redhat.com/"

REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux 7"
REDHAT_BUGZILLA_PRODUCT_VERSION=7.2
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT="Red Hat Enterprise Linux"
REDHAT_SUPPORT_PRODUCT_VERSION="7.2"
```

Unfortunately, it is a shared server, and I cannot change the content of the file. Is there any way to work around this problem?